# auto scroll to bottom when overflow auto

Tags: jquery, scroll

does anyone know how to automatically jump to the bottom of a scrollable area by event in jquery ( or even javascript if no easy jquery solution)?

regards

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<div id="myDiv" style="height:300px;overflow:auto;">
    <p>my content here</p>
</div>

var myDiv = $("#myDiv");
myDiv.animate({ scrollTop: myDiv.attr("scrollHeight") - myDiv.height() }, 3000);
```

**Edit:**

jQuery 1.6 introduced `.prop` and changed the meaning of `.attr` thus `$("#someDiv").attr("scrollHeight")` won't work anymore.

Need to be changed to: `$("#someDiv").prop("scrollHeight")`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194837/somediv-attrscrollheight-not-working-in-jquery-1-6-1).

Answer (score 5):

```
myDiv.attr("scrollHeight")
```

won't work in recent jQuery versions. You will need to resort to:

```
myDiv[0].scrollHeight
```

Comment: True, I'll edit the accepted answer with this correct warning.

Comment: this is a very important observation

Answer (score 0):

`mm.prop("scrollHeight")` does the trick (for jQuery 1.6 and forward).