# get height for a div with overflow:auto;

Tags: jquery, height, scrolltop

i have a div with height:100px and overflow:auto
the content is dynamic.

i want scroll the div in the bottom

i tried with

```
$("#chat_content").scrollTop($("#chat_content").height());
```

but if the content is bigger than 100px 
$("#chat_content").height() returns 100 and the div isn't scrolled on the bottom

how can i do?

thanks

Comment: Might be the same issue as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522579/how-do-i-get-the-real-height-of-a-overflow-hidden-or-overflow-scroll-div

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530829/auto-scroll-to-bottom-when-overflow-auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530829/auto-scroll-to-bottom-when-overflow-auto)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Get the [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight) property from the underlying DOM element:

```
$("#chat_content").scrollTop($("#chat_content").get(0).scrollHeight);
```

Comment: +1 For scrollHeight! :) Side note: using `$()[0]` is faster than `$().get(0)`

Answer (score 6):

try `$("#chat_content").scrollTop($("#chat_content").get(0).scrollHeight);`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just wrap the internal content in a div and then just change your ".height" call to

```
$("#chat_content").scrollTop($("#chat_content div").height());
```