# How to let scrollbar keep up with growing height when scroll:auto?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` which has the property `scroll:auto`. When text is added to the `<div>` and the height exceeds the default height, I have to scroll down to see the latest lines of text added. I want the latest line of text to always be visible. If I could do that, I could just use scroll:none instead of auto. How can I achieve that? I hope you understand what I mean.

**Update:** BilgehanKorkmaz's solution works, but not after a while. If I enter A LOT of text the scrolling doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Set scroll height value to .scrollTop():

```
$("div").scrollTop($("div").get(0).scrollHeight);
```

Comment: This works maybe for the first say 100 lines added to the div, but after a while it won't work anymore. The scrollbar gets tiny and doesn't scroll down.

Comment: You right. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235614/get-height-for-a-div-with-overflowauto

Answer (score 0):

You already tried `height:auto;`? I don't understood very well, so.. if possible, show exemple on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.position().top`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to get the position of the new element and use [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to scroll to the correct position:

```
var myDiv = $("#myID");

$("button").click(function(){
    var newelementtext = "<p>Your element</p>";

    var el = $(newp).appendTo(myDiv);
    myDiv.scrollTop(el.position().top);
});
```