# Scroll the page when the footer dynamically grows

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, footer

I have links within my footer, which when they are clicked, reveal hidden content.

So they're just hidden `<ul>` elements which are shown using jQuery `slideToggle();`

The problem I'm having is when I do this, I then physically have to scroll the page.  How can I force the window to scroll on its own?

I tried using scrollTo but that didn't seem to work.

Is it possibly the div that the footer resides in that is causing this?

```
<div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p onclick="showdivs('news');">
                        + News</p>
                    <ul id="news" class="subitems" style="width: 94px;">
                    <li>Item #1</li>
                    <li>Item #2</li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
```

Javascript - I know I can just do this with a .click event:

```
   function showdivs(id) {
        jQuery('.subitems').hide();
        jQuery('#' + id).slideToggle('slow');
    }
```

CSS:

```
#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#navigation ul
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #808080;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    display: inline;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#navigation li p
{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #009;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation li p:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#navigation li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#navigation li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#navigation li ul
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 25px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#navigation li li
{
    list-style: none;
    display: list-item;
}
#navigation li li a
{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 9px;
    max-width: 120px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/line.png);
}
#navigation li li a:hover
{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have?

Comment: Code (javascript, html and CSS) posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's [`.scrollTop(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function with `$(document)`, passing it the top of the element that's been toggled on:

```
jQuery('#' + id).slideToggle('slow', function () {
    $(document).scrollTop($(this).offset().top);
});
```

Use the `callback` parameter of [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle) to ensure that the page is scrolled down *after* the animation has completed (this may have been your problem originally).

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JU3xj/

---

If you want to animate the scrolling, you can do that too:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top
}, 500); // Adjust as needed.
```

Which you would use instead of the `.scrollTop()` call:

```
function showdivs(id) {
    jQuery('.subitems').hide();
    jQuery('#' + id).slideToggle('slow', function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uktmR/

Comment: That seems to work but it's a bit jarring/jerky - is there a way to smooth it?

Comment: @Jack: Sure thing, you can animate the `scrollTop` property.

Comment: When I try your animate function I get jQuery(this).offset is null

Comment: @Jack: I will need more information than that--Are you getting this error in the example? What browsers is it occurring in?

Comment: FireFox - firebug on page load - exact error: jQuery(this).offset() is null  - I place this code right above my showDiv function, or should it go somewhere else?         jQuery("html, body").animate({
            'scrollTop': jQuery(this).offset().top
        }, 500); // Adjust as needed.

Comment: @Jack: I think that's my mistake--I should have been more clear. The animate code should replace `jQuery('#' + id).slideToggle('slow');` in your `showDiv` function from your original post.

Comment: if that replaces the showDivs code, how do I select which div to show?

Comment: @Jack: I've updated the answer to include the entire `showdivs` function.

Answer (score 1):

navigation.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight is what you need, right ?

Comment: I want the page to scroll down, when the footer grows.  Do you mean footer.scrollTo ?

Comment: nope scrollTop...

this should work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530829/auto-scroll-to-bottom-when-overflow-auto

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/JU3xj/3/

First we create a plugin called scrollTo:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
        });
    }
});
```

Then, we just append it to whatever element we want to scroll to:

```
$('.return').click(function(){
    $('#navigation').scrollTo(300,'linear');
});
```