# Div refresh and scroll bar issue

Tags: php, javascript, html, refresh

I've the following Javascript code :

```
<script> 
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#loaddiv').load('tables.php');
}, 1000);
</script>
```

And

```
<div id="loaddiv">
<div style="float: left; width:650px; height:99%; border:2px solid #000; 
 overflow:auto; background-color:#FFF;">
 <?php 
 index_table();
 ?>
</div>
</div>
```

The above Div is meant to refresh its content after 1 second. Now the output of this content is a table that has multiple rows based on user submission. When the number of rows exceeds the height of the screen , the scroll bar will show up. In which you will have the ability to scroll down to see the added rows.

Now the problem starts from here, as this Div refresh the scroll bar automatically reset to top.  Which makes it difficult to see the rest of the rows.

How to stop the scroll bar from resetting to top when a Div being refreshed ? Or if its possible to automatically scroll down when new rows are been inserted.

Thank You !

Comment: good idea is that only fetch latest data from php & append to existing record of div

Comment: @GBD Ok but i have an additional options for each row when being under admin session, in which "admin" could not edit or delete because of the scrolling. :/

Comment: does the scroll bar come for the div #loaddiv or the whole window ?

Comment: @air4x The scroll bar comes for the div loaddiv only. Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. This seems to be working.

```
$('#loaddiv').load('tables.php', function() {
  $(this).scrollTop($(this).prop("scrollHeight") - $(this).height());
});
```

I got it from one of the answers in [auto scroll to bottom when overflow auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530829/auto-scroll-to-bottom-when-overflow-auto).

Comment: thanks for your time, I've tested the code you've provided and the page keeps scrolling to top. I really don't understand why its not working with me. I've googled the net many times and could not find any solution :/.

Comment: can you give a link to a demo page?

Comment: Well its in my localhost, but I'm working now to upload a the two files to my web hosting, as soon i'm done I'll provide you with a URL. Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

```
var isScrolling = false;
var lastScrollPos = 0;
var counter = 0;
$(function() {

    $('#loaddiv').on('scroll', function() {
        isScrolling = true;
        lastScrollPos = this.scrollTop;
    });


    refreshTimer = setInterval(refreshContent, 1000);

    function refreshContent() {
        if (!isScrolling) {
            $('#loaddiv').load('tables.php').scrollTop(lastScrollPos);
        }
        isScrolling = false;
    }

});​
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the code, but I've tested it and the problem is that the div stopped refreshing :/. Only way to see the new inserted rows is by doing browser refresh. Please help me :( !

Comment: I've copied the code you've provided me and pasted on top of my original Javascript code. So its like I'm pasting the same code as yours :P.

Comment: I've checked firefox firbug and i'm not getting any errors. Is it working on your side? I mean i randomly created another test file and added your code, and placed div loaddiv..The div won't refresh.Hmm Can't figure out what is going on! :(