# Reload div content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my code:

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible; height:300px; width:300px;" id="textDiv">
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id");
while($queryVar = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $queryVar['id'].". ".$queryVar['text']."<br>";
}
?>
</div>
<div id="postComment">
<textarea id="text" onKeyPress="if(window.event.keyCode==13) postComment()"     cols="30" rows="1" style="border: solid 1px #888;"></textarea>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function postComment()
{
var textVar = document.getElementById('text').value;
$("#text").val("");
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "controllers/sendCommentController.php",
    data: 'text=' + textVar,
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $("#textDiv").hide().fadeIn('fast');
    }
})
}
</script>
```

As you can see when you hit enter in the textarea, sendCommentController.php executes (a simple mysql insert query). I want my textDiv to be reloaded with its content. .load() didn't really work or I just messed up, it loads another textDiv div into my existing one... Please help :( In addition, how should I make the div's scrollbar always positioned bottom? It won't really work with .load either. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function postComment()
{
var textarea = $("#text");
var textVar = $.trim(textarea.val());
textarea.val("");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controllers/sendCommentController.php",
    data: 'text=' + textVar,
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $("#textDiv").hide().html(msg).fadeIn('fast');
    }
})
}
```

Probably, change this to POST instead of GET.

Comment: So I guess I should echo out the results in the php file?

Answer (score 1):

You're not appending the new content in the callback.

```
success: function(msg)
{
    $("#textDiv").append(msg).hide().fadeIn('fast');
}
```

For your scrolling question, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530859/3189029).

Comment: It still doesn't refresh the div content. :s

Comment: `.append` will only add to the content. change that to `.html` if you want to replace the content completely.